# Trying to add the exchnage api to my project

Tags: java

I would like to use the open source EXchange api ( a Maven project)
   https://github.com/timmolter/XChange in my project. to talk to bit coin exchnages on a project i'm working on

I followed the steps at getting started https://github.com/timmolter/XChange/wiki/Getting-Started-with-XChange-for-Noobies
This created about 20 projects. It has a project called
exchange-examples where I was able to put in my own class and write code to talk to the Exchange API

I have a project Iv been working on and would like to be able to have the exchnage api in it.  I was assumming I would have to add all the jar files that the exchnage-example project has to my my project,

When I looked at the exchnage-example project java build path for Libraies it had a folder called Maven Dependecies.

I'm assuming all the jar files under that folder I would add to my project??
in the listing of libraies some lines that did not have the name of a jar file, but just a file path. ( xchange-core ) when I clicked on it I would get
    is not module
     access rules-no rules defined
     native libary location -non
I dont know how to add that to my new peoject.

Comment: You could add the JARs manually, but usually you don't want to handle such dependencies manually. Create a Maven (or Gradle) project and then just add the dependency to your Maven POM file as shown here: https://github.com/timmolter/XChange#maven. Having done that, `mvn clean install` will pull all dependencies into your project, even transitive ones.

Comment: I wanted the sdk to be in my eclipse project, I'm assuming your solution would be for a maven project?

Comment: Yes, and Eclipse has good support for Maven to keep the libraries pulled in via Maven in sync with the Eclipse project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get everything with a Maven project, your pom.xml should include this and will automatically handle the dependencies.  If you want to use the JARs or just drag the packages into your src folder, you will have to download all of the dependencies yourself.  I would only recommend doing this after you have experimented with XChange via Maven first.

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.knowm.xchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>xchange-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.knowm.xchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>xchange-bittrex</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.knowm.xchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>xchange-bitfinex</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

The first one (xchange-core) is required, and then you have to add another dependency for each exchange you wish to use.